# Two-sided ideals of $M_n(k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

In his Class Field Theory notes, J. Milne show the following example.

[image]

I can prove that $M_n(k)$ is a simple $k$-algebra by showing that the ideal generated by any matrix is necessarily $M_n(k)$ itself, but I don't understand Milne's argument. If $J$ is a nonzero ideal, then surely it has to contain a minimal left-ideal and a minimal right-ideal. How can I conclude Milne's argument to prove that $J=M_n(k)$?

PS: GT 7.15a has no information about this.

Comment: To get a better feeling for what's happening you might try to show the more general result that if $R$ is a commutative ring with $1,$ then the two-sided ideals of $M_n(R)$ are of the form $M_n(I)$ with $I$ an ideal of $R.$ The left ideals are as described by Milne. For the right ideals, do the same thing with rows rather than columns. Given Milne's second remark about $B_j,$ it should not be too hard to see that  the set of matrices with all columns zero except for the $j$th , and the $j$th is an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ is indeed a minimal ideal.

Comment: @ChrisLeary I think I can prove all of that. The proof that the two-sided ideals of $M_n(R)$ are of the form $M_n(I)$ follows by considering the top-left element of the matrices in an ideal $J\subset M_n(R)$. This is an ideal $I\subset R$ such that $M_n(I)=J$. I also understand that the $L(\{j\})$ are the minimal ideals. But I still can't see how to conclude Milne's argument.

Comment: $M_n(k)$ is simple because $k$ has only two ideals, $0$ and $k$ itself.

Comment: These parts of CFT and GT have been rewritten recently. You want GT 7.19a. I think the example in CFT originally erroneously claimed that all left and right ideals were of this form, which would have made the statement obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it seems there is an enormous gap between the content discussed before the phrase “it follows that” and the assertion after it.  All the discussion suggests is that the ideal must contain left and right ideals of those types, but it isn’t obvious why that means it would be the whole ring.

The closest thing I can see is this: use a nonzero element of the ideal, and right multiplication to get a nonzero element with exactly one nonzero column j. By the conversation, the ideal must contain $L(\{j\})$. Using more right multiplications, it must contain $L(\{i\})$ for all the other indices too. Therefore it contains their sum, which is the entire ring.

But all this hinges on explaining the line that has the word “arbitrary” on it. It apparently is supposed to convey that you can get any column vector by choosing an appropriate $A$, but this deserves more explanation than was given.